# Retrieve hash between two subroutines

Tags: perl, hash, arguments, subroutine

I would retrieve my hash table when i pass it in argument at a function. In my case, function1 return my hash table, then i pass my hash table in argument to my function2 and in my function2 i would retrieve my hash table for browse it.

```
sub function1{
    my code;
    return %hash;
}

sub function2{
    my %hash=$_[0];
    my code browse my hash;
}

my %hash = function1();
function2(%hash);
```

I have the following error : Odd number of elements in hash assignment at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to pass the hash by reference:

```
sub function1{
    # code here
    return \%hash;
}

sub function2{
    my $hashref = $_[0];

    #code to use the hash:
    foreach (keys %$hashref) { etc... }
}

my $hashref = function1();
function2($hashref);

my %realhash;
function2(\%realhash);
```

Passing by reference is a necessity when you want to pass more than one hash or array.  It is also more efficient for large amounts of data, because it doesn't make a copy.  However, if the function modifies a hash that was passed by reference, the original will be modified as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are only pulling in the first element of a list into a hash (i.e. an even sized list, hence the warning). Try this:

```
sub function1{
    my code;
    return %hash;
}

sub function2{
    my (%hash) = @_;
    my code browse my hash;
}

my %hash = function1();
function2(%hash);
```

You can get what you want with a hashref:

```
sub function1{
    my code;
    return \%hash;
}

sub function2{
    my $hash_ref=$_[0];
    my code browse my hash;
}

my $hash_ref = function1();
function2($hash_ref);
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't understood @_ and where my function1 is called.

Comment: @Tof, you might want to checkout http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html. Grabbing a copy of "Learning Perl" might not be a terrible idea either.